# Barcodescanner cordova with led light

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner, flashlight

I used plugin com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner to create app scan qr code

but i can't turn on led light in device when Scan

how to solve the problem

Thanks all you help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution.

When you scan, if you want the LED light on, just increase the volume. If want the LED light off, decrease the volume

Comment: Great, it works well on Android phones, but unfortunately not with iOS

Answer (score 1):

Just show a button to switch on torch or switch torch on for Android:

```
   cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      },
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      },
      **{
          showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
          torchOn: true, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
      }**
   );
```

Comment: { ... showTorchButton : false, torchOn: false ...} disable auto flashlight if you want turn on just follow scorpion "When you scan, if you want the LED light on, just increase the volume. If want the LED light off, decrease the volume"

Answer (score 0):

Use cordova-plugin-flashlight:

```
   function scanlicht(enable) {
        window.plugins.flashlight.available(function (isAvailable) {
           if (isAvailable) {
              if (enable) {
                 window.plugins.flashlight.switchOn(
                    function () { },
                     function () { },  
                     { intensity: 0.3}   
                 );
              } else {
                 window.plugins.flashlight.switchOff();
              }
           }
        });
     }
    function scan(){
       scanlicht(true);
       cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
             scanlicht(false);
             .... your code ....
          }, function (error) {
             scanlicht(false);
             alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          },null
       }
    }
```